# I found Great Grandfather's patents

Tags: us1151561, us1355638

I found my Great Grandfather, Morgan Doniphan Bollinger's patents from the early 1900s: #1,151,561 and #1,355,638.

Is there any way to get good copies of them?

The first of them is still in use, the Adjustable Side Hill Wagon (today used for off-road driving,) can I make any legal claim to this patent?

Answer (score 1):

The U.S. Patent Office's copy of these patents should be in the National Archives holdings. A typical patent file can contain the original specification that was submitted at the time of the application, along with the patentee's oath and correspondence between the patent office and the patentee or his attorney along with an original copy of the patent as issued. I've included a link to the National Archives online catalog listing for this series which includes a link to request copies of the files.

Since the patents would have expired more than 75 years ago, there isn't any financial gain from the patents at this time, but that doesn't diminish the genealogical value to yourself and your family.

Comment: Didn't you mean _financial gain_ instead of _finical gain_?

Comment: You are correct it should have been financial.